# replace first n occurrence of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string var with following:

```
var str = getDataValue();
//str value is in this format = "aVal,bVal,cVal,dVal,eVal"
```

Note that the value is separated by `,` respectively, and the val is not fixed / hardcoded.
How do I replace only the bVal everytime?

Comment: var res = str.replace("bVal", "your new value");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

If you use string as the regex, escape the string to prevent malicious attacks:

```
RegExp.escape = function(string) {
  return string.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}; 

new RegExp(RegExp.escape(string));
```

```js
var str = "aVal,bVal,cVal,dVal,eVal";
var rgx = 'bVal';
var x = 'replacement';
var res = str.replace(rgx, x);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Is that `rgx` supposed to be a pattern?

Comment: Originally, yes. I used a literal instead.

Comment: my bad for not making the question clear enough. but bVal is actually not harcoded. but I get the idea here. I will use string split to get bVal first before the replacement

Comment: Make sure you escape a string if using it as regex. `new RegExp(RegExp.escape(string));` it's to prevent malicious attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var targetValue = 'bVal';
 var replaceValue = 'yourValue';
 str = str.replace(targetValue , replaceValue);
```

Comment: this is the simplest way to do

Comment: my bad for not making the question clear enough. but bVal is actually not harcoded.